# Trabajar objetos en diferentes archivos python

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con un microcontrolador y me estoy equivocando al usar clases (me cuestan muchísimo).

Antes de explicar el problema, pongo en contexto: el microcontrolador me permite trabajar con dos archivos `.py`, `boot.py` que se ejecutará al arrancar el microcontrolador y el `main.py`.

La cosa está en que yo he creado una clase para poder trabajar el protocolo de comunicación y lo he guardado dentro de la carpeta `lib`. La clase es la siguiente:

```
from network import LoRa
import socket
import binascii
import time
import machine
import pycom
import config

# LoRa_config.py

class myLoRa:

    def __init__(self):
        # LoRa parameters
        self.dev_eui = config.dev_eui
        self.app_eui = config.app_eui
        self.app_key = config.app_key

        self.frequency = config.LORA_FREQUENCY
        self.dr = config.LORA_NODE_DR
        self.region = LoRa.EU868 # EUROPE

    # Inicializo la conexion
    def LoRa_join(self):
        # initialize LoRa in LORAWAN mode.
        lora = LoRa(mode=LoRa.LORAWAN, region=self.region)
        
        # set the 3 default channels to the same frequency (must be before sending the OTAA join request)
        lora.add_channel(0, frequency=self.frequency, dr_min=0, dr_max=5)
        lora.add_channel(1, frequency=self.frequency, dr_min=0, dr_max=5)
        lora.add_channel(2, frequency=self.frequency, dr_min=0, dr_max=5)

        # join a network using OTAA
        lora.join(
            activation=LoRa.OTAA,
            auth=(self.dev_eui, self.app_eui,self.app_key),
            timeout=0,
            dr=self.dr)
        
        # wait until the module has joined the network
        NumJoin = 0
        while not lora.has_joined():
            time.sleep(2.5)
            print('Trying to join...', str(NumJoin))
            if (NumJoin < 30):
                NumJoin += 1
            else:
                machine.reset()

        # remove all the non-default channels
        for i in range(3, 16):
            lora.remove_channel(i)

    # LoRa socket
    def LoRa_socket(self):
        # create a LoRa socket
        lora_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_LORA, socket.SOCK_RAW)
        # set the LoRaWAN data rate
        lora_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_LORA, socket.SO_DR, self.dr)
        # make the socket non-blocking
        lora_socket.setblocking(False)


    def LoRa_send(self, payload, lora_socket):

        print('Alcachofa')

        self.lora_socket.send(payload)

        if self.lora_socket.send(payload):
            print('Payload a lora enviado', payload)
```

Al arrancar el micro debo ejecutar las dos primeras funciones de la clase, `LoRa_join` y `LoRa_socket` pues son las que me crean la conexión para la comunicación. Para eso hago:

```
# boot.py -- run on boot-up

import pycom
import config
import binascii
import Clock
import LoRa_config # Archivo con la clase


# Paso 1 - Apagamos el led "heardbeat" para reducir consumos innecesarios.
print('Boot - Apago led heardbeat')
pycom.heartbeat(False)

# Paso 2 - Conectamos a la red LoRa.
xarxa = LoRa_config.myLoRa()
xarxa.LoRa_join()
lora_socket = xarxa.LoRa_socket()
```

Hasta aquí todo bien (aunque yo creo que de este `lora_socket = xarxa.LoRa_socket()` la salida sobra), pero ahora en el `main` quiero enviar un paquete (para hacer la prueba de que la cosa va bien) y es donde fallo. Yo hago lo siguiente:

```
# main.py
import ustruct


# Programa principal
while True:
    print('Main - HOLA')

    payload = ustruct.pack('>I', 4)
    xarxa.LoRa_send(payload, lora_socket)
```

Consigo acceder a `LoRa_send` porque me imprime "Alcachofa" pero me da el error:

> AttributeError: 'myLoRa' object has no attribute 'lora_socket'

La primera pregunta sería ¿al `main.py` está llegando `xarxa`? ¿Debería hacerla una variable global? En resumen, ¿cómo accedo a `LoRa_send()` desde el main para poder enviar el dato?

---

**EDIT A PARTIR DE LA RESPUESTA DE ABULAFIA**

Según he entendido (espero haberlo hecho bien) y he probado, ese `import boot` no hace falta hacerlo pues ya lo hace el mismo. Pues desde el `main` tengo acceso a `xarxa`. Según todo esto yo entiendo que la cosa debería quedar así (lo cual entiendo mal porque da error):

```
class myLoRa:

    def __init__(self):
        # Igual

    # Inicializo la conexion
    def LoRa_join(self):
        # Igual

    # LoRa socket
    def LoRa_socket(self):
        # igual


    def LoRa_send(self, payload):

        print('Alcachofa')

        self.lora_socket.send(payload)

        if self.lora_socket.send(payload):
            print('Payload a lora enviado', payload)
```

En archivo `boot.py` quito la igualación pues yo entiendo tengo acceso a ella al ser un `self.`:

```
# Paso 2 - Conectamos a la red LoRa.
xarxa = LoRa_config.myLoRa()
xarxa.LoRa_join()
xarxa.LoRa_socket()
```

Y en el `main.py` sin importar `boot` pues parece el ya lo hace:

```
import ustruct

# Programa principal
while True:
    print('Main - HOLA')
    payload = ustruct.pack('>I', 4)
    xarxa.LoRa_send(payload)
    break
```

El problema persiste:

> AttributeError: 'myLoRa' object has no attribute 'lora_socket'

Yo creo que mentalmente debo obviar el hecho de trabajar con `boot.py` y `main.py` y pensar como si lo del `boot` está simplemente antes del bucle `while`. Siendo así, entiendo que el problema está en que no se trabajar las clases y `lora_socket` o no la estoy sacando bien o luego al emplearla en el `LoRa_send` no la llamo correctamente.

---

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Las variables que usas en un script son visibles sólo desde el script, a menos que las importes en otros. En tu caso creo que bastaría con añadir a `main`  la línea `from boot import xarxa` No obstante ese import causará que se ejecute el contenido de `boot.py` y esa es la parte que no tengo clara, pues aparentemente ese archivo debe ejecutarse una sola vez. La dificultad que veo aqui es cómo ejecutar solo una vez boot aunque se ejecuten varias veces main, ya que si no me equivoco eso es lo que debe ocurrir. ¿Puedes aclarar cómo sería el flujo de ejecución deseado?

Comment: Efectivamente `boot.py` solo debe ejecutarse al inicio. No tengo muy claro a que te refieres por flujo, pero lo dicho, el boot se ejecuta una vez y luego ya trabajamos en el `main.py` hasta que yo le haga un reset al aparato, lo apague, etc. Según mi código actual debe hacer: `boot` > `imprimir hola, enviar un 4` > `imprimir hola, enviar un 4` > `imprimir hola, enviar un 4` > etc

Comment: La pregunta iba más bien en la línea de si se puede lanzar `main.py` varias veces (es decir, una vez haya terminado, lanzarlo una segunda vez, una tercera, etc.) y en este caso si debe evitarse que boot se vuelva a ejecutar en cada uno de los lanzamientos de main. O si por el contrario main se ejecuta una sola vez (y debe comenzar por invocar a boot). O si boot.py se ejecuta manualmente desde línea de comandos antes de ejecutar después main.py (y por qué habría de ser así y no podría ejecutarlo el propio main.py)

Comment: Vale, si no te entiendo mal, la respuesta es que ambos ficheros se ejecutan una única vez. Primero boot y luego main, lo que pasa que para que a mi me funcione infinito, yo tengo un bucle `while` en mi main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Teoria

Un módulo no es más que un script python que puede ser "invocado" desde otro script mediante la sentencia `import`. Eso no solo ejecuta el módulo, sino que hace accesibles todas sus variables, clases y funciones al script que haya hecho el `import`.

Por tanto si tienes un fichero llamado `a.py` que contiene esto:

```
# Contenido de a.py
def funcion():
   return 42

sentido = funcion()
```

Y otro script llamado `b.py` que contiene esto:

```
# Contenido de b.py
import a

print(a.sentido)
```

saldrá 42 como resultado. Lo que ocurre es que, ante la sentencia `import a` se ejecutará `a.py` y *además*, todos los símbolos (funciones, variables, clases, etc.) definidas en ese script serán ahora accesibles dentro del **espacio de nombres** `a`. Eso es lo que me permite acceder a `a.sentido` que valdrá 42. También me permitirá acceder a `a.funcion()` si lo necesitara.

El `import` admite otras sintaxis, como por ejemplo cambiar el nombre del espacio de nombres resultante: `import a as modulo_a` por ejemplo. En este caso ocurre lo mismo de antes, pero el espacio de nombres se llamará `modulo_a`, por tanto tendría que poner `modulo_a.sentido` para obtener el 42.

También puedes importar un solo símbolo al espacio de nombres actual, usando la sintaxis `from a import sentido` por ejemplo. En ese caso el módulo `a.py` se ejecuta completo, igual que en los casos anteriores, pero además su símbolo `sentido` queda accesible para el módulo actual como parte del espacio de nombres global. Esto significa que no necesitas escribir `a.sentido`, sino que puedes poner simplemente `sentido`.

Sabiendo todas estas cosas ya estamos listos para resolver tu problema.

### Solución

¿Quieres que desde  `main` se ejecute `boot` y luego poder acceder a la variable `xarxa` definido en él? De acuerdo con lo antes dicho tienes dos opciones:

1. Primera opción

   ```
   # Comienzo de de main.py
   from boot import xarxa
   ```

   Esto ejecutará `boot.py` completo y además te dejará la variable `xarxa` en él definida accesible desde el espacio de nombres global. Es decir, ya puedes usar `xarxa` sin más desde `main.py`
2. Segunda opción

   ```
   # Comienzo de main.py
   import boot
   ```

   En este caso ejecutas `boot.py` sin importar ninguno de sus símbolos al espacio de nombres global. Aún así los tienes todos accesibles como parte del espacio de nombres `boot`, por lo que desde main puedes acceder a `boot.xarxa` y también a `boot.lora_socket`  y cualquiera de las variables o funciones que hayas definido en `boot.py`

## Actualización

Tras leer la actualziación de la pregunta, comento un par de cosas.

Todo lo antes dicho, en mi opinión, sigue siendo necesario pues de otro modo no sé cómo en `main` tendrías acceso a la variable `xarxa`, ya que ésta se define en `boot.py` y desde `main.py` no lo estás ejecutando.

Aparte de eso, tienes un error que no había visto en mi primera lectura, y es en el siguiente método de la clase `myLoRa`:

```
    # LoRa socket
    def LoRa_socket(self):
        # create a LoRa socket
        lora_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_LORA, socket.SOCK_RAW)
        # set the LoRaWAN data rate
        lora_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_LORA, socket.SO_DR, self.dr)
        # make the socket non-blocking
        lora_socket.setblocking(False)
```

Este método define una variable `lora_socket`, pero esta variable es local al método y desaparece cuando éste finaliza. Entiendo que lo que quieres es que esa variable sea parte del objeto, pues más adelante intentas acceder a ella con la sintaxis `self.lora_socket`.

Para resolverlo debes inicializar la variable como `self.lora_socket`, en lugar de `lora_socket` a secas. Es decir:

```
    # LoRa socket
    def LoRa_socket(self):
        # create a LoRa socket
        self.lora_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_LORA, socket.SOCK_RAW)
        # set the LoRaWAN data rate
        self.lora_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_LORA, socket.SO_DR, self.dr)
        # make the socket non-blocking
        self.lora_socket.setblocking(False)
```

Es posible que tengas errores similares en otras partes del código, pues no lo he revisado a fondo. La idea en todo caso es siempre la misma. Cada vez que quieras crear o acceder a una variable del objeto, debes poner `self.` delante. De otro modo se trataría de una variable local del método que existe sólo mientras el método se ejecuta.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta a partir de lo que entiendo con tu respuesta. Muchas gracias

Comment: @Lleims Ok, he actualizado la respuesta. Mira si te sirve

Comment: Por si alguien lo necesita, ¡El problema eran los selfs! No sé como, pero en el `main.py` ya se importan los datos del `reboot.py`. GRACIAS

Comment: @Lleims Me alegro de que ya te funcione, pero lo que dices del main me tiene intrigado. Es imposible que accedas a variables de boot si no las importas. Obviamente el `main.py` que has mostrado es sólo un fragmento del que realmente usas y en el tuyo algo más haces que explicaría por qué te funciona.

Comment: Me sabe mal defraudarte pero ese es todo el main jajaj. Obviamente es un main para testear, pero eso es todo. Yo imagino que esto debe estar internamente programado en el microcontrolador para que suceda.

Comment: Buf.. con lo que me incomodan a mi los misterios inexplicables :-) A lo mejor es que el main es importado desde otro lugar. Quizás todo eso sea parte de algún _framework_ que integra todo. La verdad, me quedo con la curiosidad de ver todo el código para descifrar el enigma.

Comment: Es una lopy4. Mira el punto 3, de este [enlace](https://docs.pycom.io/gettingstarted/#creating-a-project-in-pymakr), yo pienso que es eso que tu dices.

Comment: Ah, todo aclarado. Micropython es un framework que se ocupa él mismo de cargar `boot.py` y  después `main.py`. Aunque no he rebuscado los detalles, parece claro que de algún modo consigue inyectar en el espacio de nombres de `main` las variables que hayan sido definidas en `boot.py`. No me había dado cuenta de que tu pregunta era sobre micropython y me estaba despistando mucho cómo un módulo podría acceder a variables de otro sin importarlas.